# Does AWS have any firewall products?

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-ec2, firewall

For my EC2 instance on Apache, does AWS have any firewall product besides Cloudfront?

Comment: No... the EC2 (AWS) image has no firewall as there is no need as its controlled by (EC2 Security Groups), which is better than an internal firewall. You can however install your own within the EC2 instance and then open a port range within the  EC2 Security Group and Settings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, AWS offers what they call AWS "WAF", short for Web Application Firewall. As the name implies, it's intended purpose is to help you protect your applications from exploits that are known to affect availability, security, as well as consume excessive resources.

AWS WAF allows you to control traffic (allow/block) to your web apps by creating customized rules. WAF is free to use, to sign up use the following link: [AWS Web Application Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/details/)

Comment: So it stands front of ec2 instance running a website?

Comment: Well, you technically would not want it too if you are already using Cloudfront. Based on my limited understanding, you would want to use one, or the other, but not both. I am by no means an expert in this subject, but I have had the opportunity to make mistakes and learn. Cloudfront can add numerous security (including firewall) enhancements to a website, where as WAF would intuitively seem to be used for a separate purpose, such as running a custom app, etc. Hope that his helps. Are you having any specific problem with anything?

Comment: Yeah getting lots of invalid traffic according to google adsense so I signed up cloudflare From their logs It's like fake bots, ddos traffic, sql probes and all paraphernalia you can imagine! So wondering if any other solution is better